What is the reason for these strange oscillations? Issue with Desmos?
Take a partition of $\Bbb R^2_{\gt 0}$ by the union of functions indexed by real $t\ge 0$
$$\mathcal F:=\bigg \lbrace \mathcal M[\chi_t(x)]\cup \mathcal M\bigg[\frac{1}{1-\chi_t(x)}\bigg] \bigg \rbrace$$
where
$$\mathcal M[\chi_t(x)]:=\int_{(0,1)} \chi_t(x)x^{s-1}~dx=  2\sqrt{\frac{t}{s}}K_1(2\sqrt{ts})=\Phi_t(s)$$
and
$$\mathcal M\bigg[\frac{1}{1-\chi_t(x)}\bigg] :=\int_{(0,1)} \frac{1}{1-\chi_t(x)}x^{s-1}~dx= \Psi_t(s)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \Phi_{tn}(s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2\sqrt{\frac{tn}{s}}K_1(2\sqrt{ts})$$
for $K_1$ Bessel function.
Consider the functions indexed again by $t$
$$H_t(x)=-\frac{\Phi'{_t}(s)}{\Phi{_t}(s)\Psi_t(s)}  $$
This set of functions forms a real analytic partition (even a foliation) of $\Bbb R^2_{\gt 0}$ we have that $$\bigcup_{t\ge 0} H_t(x)=\Bbb R^2_{\gt 0}$$

But I am curious, what is the reason for the oscillations in the plot? Is this an issue with Desmos?

Here is a picture of the partition. Link to the plot: Desmos Plot.


Link to Desmos graph?

@SohamSaha yes of course one second

@SohamSaha https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dmlgckixcd

Indeed, Mathematica 14 gives the following graph for $x \mapsto H_t(x)$ with $t = \frac{1}{10}, \frac{2}{10}, \ldots, \frac{100}{10}$:

Here, I utilized the following formulas
$$ -\frac{\Phi_t'(s)}{\Phi_t(s)}
= \frac{1}{2 s} + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{t}{s}} \frac{K_0(2\sqrt{st}) + K_2(2\sqrt{st})}{K_1(2\sqrt{st})} \tag{1} $$
and
$$ \Psi_t(s) = \frac{1}{s} + \frac{1}{2s} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sinh^2 \xi} \exp\left(-\frac{st}{2\xi}\right) \, \mathrm{d}\xi. \tag{2} $$
(The formula $\text{(2)}$ can be proved by invoking DLMF 10.32.10 along with $\Phi_0(s) = \frac{1}{s}$.)
Analytic approach also hints that wavy behavior is likely not occur. Indeed, plugging $\text{(1)}$ and $\text{(2)}$ into the definition of $H_t(s)$, we get
$$ H_t(s) = f(\sqrt{ts}) $$
where
$$ f(z) = 
\frac{\displaystyle 1 + z \left( \frac{K_0(2z) + K_2(2z)}{K_1(2z)} \right)}{ \displaystyle 2 + \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sinh^2 \xi} \exp\left(-\frac{z^2}{2\xi}\right) \, \mathrm{d}\xi}. $$
This means that the graph of $H_t(s)$ and $H_{t'}(s)$ for $t, t' > 0$ are just horizontally dilated version of each other. So, if the graph of $z \mapsto H_1(z)$ is not monotone increasing, then $H_t(s)$'s cannot form a foliation.
